# can't access method of public class from inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, methods

I'm having a really strange (to me) problem.  I'm somewhat of a beginner.

Basically, I'm following the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2mMwWiZBmE):

But I want to create an actual class, Player, instead of using an Array of Strings like the author of this video does.

But while doing that, I came across this strange problem...

When I simply create an instance of the Class, Player from inside the Fragment, I can't subsequently access it's methods from inside that same fragment.  When I try to like this:

```
package com.tba.excercise_tabbed_lists;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Frag_Fave extends ListFragment {

Player P0001 = new Player();
Player P0002 = new Player();
Player P0003 = new Player();
Player P0004 = new Player();

P0001.setName("");


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout_favorites, container, false);


    return rootView;
}
}
```

... Android Studio highlights setName is red and says, "cannot resolve symbol 'setName'.

This seems so basic and weird.  I'm sure it's something silly, but Ive researched and can't seem to find a Q/A similar enough for me to understand.

I can do the same thing from my MainActivity and it works fine.  If it can create the class instance from inside the Fragment, then why can't it access a method of that instance???

Here is my code for the class Player:

```
package com.tba.excercise_tabbed_lists;


public class Player {

private String name;

public Player(){

}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Comment: move `P0001.setName("");` to inside `onCreateView` or another function

Comment: Call `P0001.setName("");` method inside any method

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP is a beginner who is having problems. You can't downvote him for that! His question looks fine to me.

Comment: Hi there OP. Don't worry about adding "solved" to the title and putting solutions in the question - we prefer questions to be kept in a reasonably pristine state here, so they follow the Q&A format in perpetuity. If you wish to add a substantive solution yourself however (i.e. other than you solved it) you may do so below.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering: we recommend that people don't worry about voting too much. The community view is that people may vote for any reason at all, as long as they are not voting by user.

Comment: @halfer I think as long as the upvote/downvote buttons are there and people are using them in a way that doesn't seem to figure, I don't see anything wrong with asking the downvoter what their reason is. It could help the OP, the downvoter, me and/or anyone else reading.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering, sure - ask away. My experience here is that asking doesn't help, since the actual voter is long gone, and thus the won't see it. These sorts of comments very rarely get definitive answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your code, OOPS concept never allow to assign outside method,
You can declare or assign values outside method, but can't call method outside methods.

So try below code, hope it will work.

```
//P0001.setName("");   comment this outside and write it in method

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout_favorites, container, false);

   P0001.setName("");
   return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout_favorites, container, false);

           P0001.setName("");

      return rootView;
}
```

Comment: You could also call `P0001.setName("");` in another method. The key is that you must be in a method when you call it. That is unless `P0001` was static and then you could operate on it in a `static { ... }` block.